# Wrong number of results in Google Scrape with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to learn web scraping and I am facing a freaky issue... My task is to search Google for news on a topic in a certain date range and count the number of results.

my simple code is

```
import requests,  bs4

payload = {'as_epq': 'James Clark', 'tbs':'cdr:1,cd_min:1/01/2015,cd_max:1/01/2015','tbm':'nws'}    
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=payload)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
elems = soup.select('#resultStats')
print(elems[0].getText())
```

And the result I get is

```
About 8,600 results
```

So apparently all works... apart from the fact that the result is wrong. If I open the URL in Firefox (I can obtain the complete URL with r.url)

```
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&as_epq=James+Clark&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F01%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F01%2F2015
```

I see that the results are actually **only 2**, and if I manually download the HTML file, open the page source and search for **id="resultStats"** I find that the number of results is indeed 2!

Can anybody help me to understand why searching for the same id tag in the saved HTML file and in the soup item lead to two different numerical results?

************** UPDATE
It seems that the problem is the custom date range that does not get processed correctly by requests.get. If I use the same URL with **selenium** I get the correct answer

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
elems = soup.select('#resultStats')
print(elems[0].getText())
```

And the answer is

```
2 results (0.09 seconds)
```

The problem is that this methodology seems to be more cumbersome because I need to open the page in Firefox...

Comment: when I search g.news without a date range, I get ~8600 entries too. So it seems that there is a silent error in code passing the date arguments? Not a python person, so can't recommend a debug strategy. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that is causing this issue. First, it wants day and month parts of date in 2 digits and it is also expecting a user-agent string of some popular browser. Following code should work:

```
import requests,  bs4

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
}
payload = {'as_epq': 'James Clark', 'tbs':'cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/2015,cd_max:01/01/2015', 'tbm':'nws'}
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=payload, headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
print soup.find(id='resultStats').text
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Vikas' answer, Google will also fail to use 'custom date range' for some user-agents. That is, for certain user-agents, Google will simply search for 'recent' results instead of your specified date range.

I haven't detected a clear pattern in which user-agents will break the custom date range. It seems that including a language is a factor.

Here are some examples of user-agents that break `cdr`:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr-FR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27`

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need in `selenium`, you're looking for this:

```py
soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
# About 10,700,000 results
```

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": 'James Clark',  # query
    "hl": "en",          # lang
    "gl": "us",          # country to search from
    "tbm": "nws",        # news filter
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

# if used without "nobr" selector and previous_sibling it will return seconds as well: (0.41 secods)
number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
print(number_of_results)

# About 10,700,000 results
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google News Results API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to find which selectors will make the work done, or figure out why some of them don't return data you want also they should, bypass blocks from search engines, and maintain it over time.

Instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want, fast.

Code to integrate for your case:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": 'James Clark',
  "tbm": "nws",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

number_of_results = results['search_information']['total_results']
print(number_of_results)

# 14300000
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.