# Different Scrapy Requests, Same Output Value

Tags: python, scrapy

For a project, I am running a broad number of Scrapy requests for certain search terms. These requests use the same search terms but different time horizons, as shown through the dates in the URLs below.

Despite the different dates and different pages the URLs refer to, I am receiving the same value as output for all requests. It appears like the script is taking the first value obtained and is assigning the same output to all subsequent requests.

Does anyone know what could be the reasons for these "result duplications" and how this can be solved?

```
import scrapy

 class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2004%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2004&tbm=nws',
                  'https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2005%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2005&tbm=nws',
                  'https://www.google.com/search?q=Activision&biw=1280&bih=607&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F2006%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2006&tbm=nws',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'search_title': response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get(),
            'results': response.css('#resultStats::text').get(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
        yield item
```

Please find below the outputs I am receiving for the given requests:

[image: Output]

Comment: Do you have this "same" output for the three url's available?

Comment: I have just added the output to the original question text

Comment: What were you expecting in the output? The `search_title` is the same for all your  URLs, so it will be the same in the output. The `url` value clearly is different. And `results` is probably the same because that is what Google decides to give you.

Comment: These should all refer to different webpages and hence yield different results. The resultStats value for the search range "2005" is for instance `<div id="resultStats">About 455 results<nobr>`, according to the source text

Comment: When you open a URL in a browser you might very well see different results. Google likely recognises that you're a bot and returns some generic cached values (e.g. 14,500,000) What you need to focus on is the results you can see by running `scrapy shell`. *That* is what the spider works with - not what you see in the browser. If you see those values in the shell, then that is what you will get when you run your spider.

Comment: Google would normally block the requests once it recognises a bot, that is at least my experience from VBA scraping. Also, when I am adding various search terms to the list (instead of just changing the dates), the script yields different results for each of the requests.

Comment: It seems like you were right and Google is indeed just returning some generic values from its cache. This is striking as the requests are working well with VBA, just a lot slower than Python.

Comment: Maybe it is because they are slower that they work.

Comment: Yes I either thought about speed or about the way the values are read. In the case of VBA script it happens by the script opening FireFox, loading the page and then automatically reading the specific parts from the page source. Python/Scrapy is not using a browser for its requests as it seems, which Google may notice.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a thread [discussing a similar problem with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531214/wrong-number-of-results-in-google-scrape-with-python). The solution was here to add headers to the script, hence making the script use a browser as User-Agent.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
}
payload = {'as_epq': 'James Clark', 'tbs':'cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/2015,cd_max:01/01/2015', 'tbm':'nws'}
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=payload, headers=headers)
```

The approach to apply the headers reference to Scrapy [seems to be different though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220174/how-to-add-headers-to-scrapy-crawlspider-requests). Does anyone know how it can best be included in the script, particularly with reference to `start_urls`?